# Divide by zero error in while executing the batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wrote a batch script to count number file in directory. after that i need to assign the same value to a variable.

```
@for /f %%a in ('2^>nul dir "C:\Users\robert\Desktop\Resouces" /a-d/b/-o/-p/s^|find /v /c ""') do set n=%%a @echo Totalfiles: %n%.

set /A "{$temp.DataTask1[1]/inout[1]/p_FileName}=%n%"
```

But this throws divide by zero error. Kindly let me know my mistake here. {$temp.DataTask1[1]/inout[1]/p_FileName} is name of the variable.

Comment: The `/` in your strange variable name is considered as the division operator by `set /A`, but since you are not intending to do any arithmetics, simply remove `/A`. There should be a line-break before the `@echo`. You do actually not need to assign to an interim variable `n`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the "set" command without /A parameter to resolve problem of "divide by zero"

```
@for /f %%a in ('2^>nul dir "C:\Users\robert\Desktop\Resouces" /a-d/b/-o/-p/s^|find /v /c ""') do set n=%%a 
@echo Totalfiles: %n%.

set "{$temp.DataTask1[1]/inout[1]/p_FileName}=%n%"
```